# Access a bundle (sncRedisBundle) from within an Extension

Tags: symfony

I have successfully installed the sncRedisBundle and used the predis element of it within a controller, using:

```
$this->container->get('snc_redis.default');
```

I want to do the same within an extension:

```
class MyExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
    */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        $redis = $container->get('snc_redis.default');
    }
}
```

But I get:

```
The service definition "snc_redis.default" does not exist.
```

Is this a scoping issue? How do I access redis from within an Extension?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't access the service because it hasn't been loaded yet. Once every single `load` method have been called then you can access a service.

Comment: Yeah, I came to that conclusion in the end. Was hoping to use that area as somewhere to initialise things on server start, but it didn't work out due to some of the dependencies.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
services:
    site:
        class: Emlaktown\AppBundle\Site\Site
        arguments: [%api_url%, "@request_stack", "@service_container"]
```

....

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
```

....

```
public function __construct($apiUrl, RequestStack $requestStack, Container $container)
    {
        $this->client = new Client($apiUrl);
        $this->redis = $container->get('snc_redis.cache');
        $request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        $this->client->setDefaultOption('Accept-Language', $request->getLocale());
    }
```

Comment: Okay, this is a bit after the fact, so I will have to look into what I was trying to use it on. I have seen your answer and once I have had a chance to check it, I will hopefully be able to accept it. Thanks for spending the time to answer the question!

Comment: In reality, I just injected redis, rather than the container, but the principle is the same.